# Form submit button losing value attribute in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

We have baked a crud with validations. All seems ok. 
However, when we hit the submit button,

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('go for it'); ?>
```

and if we get validation errors, the HTML submit button loses is value attribute.

Before hitting submit we get this output:

```
<input  type="submit" value="go for it"/>
```

After hitting submit we get this output:

```
<input type="submit" value></input>
```

Here's the full ctp code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ScheduleAccess'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
    <fieldset class="short">
        <legend>Bla bla</legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('schedule_es', array('label' => 'Bla bla (es)')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('schedule_en', array('label' => 'Ble ble (en)')); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="short">
        <legend>Last Bla bla</legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('last_entry', array(
                                                    'dateFormat' => 'YMD',
                                                    'timeFormat' => '24',
                                                    'label'=>'until:'
                                                    )); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="full">
        <legend>terms</legend>
        <div class="medium wysihtml5">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('free_entry_day_time_es', array('label' => 'Things (es)')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('free_entries_and_discounts_es', array('label' => 'More things (es)')); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="medium wysihtml5">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('free_entry_day_time_en', array('label' => 'Things (en)')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('free_entries_and_discounts_en', array('label' => 'More things (en)')); ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<?php   //echo $this->Element('admin/save'); ?>
<?php   echo $this->Form->submit('go for it'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Has anyone found a similar issue?

Comment: are you sure you don't have any `if` conditions somewhere in your code? Can you post the whole view?

Comment: @AD7six - updated the question with the whole ctp code.

Comment: Looks like you need to do some debugging then =). Either the code isn't doing what you expect (`debug($this->Form->submit('go for it')` for example) or there is js corrupting your form, or something else unexpected.

Comment: Indeed. This code has to many things bootstrap, angular... jquery... a js mess. Perhaps an onClick event is trigger or something. What I wish to know is that if Cake php on other forms, normally change the button value to something like "saving...", because, clearly something is happening to that button after we hit it and we get validation errors. If cake has something on it, them where should I take a look? (find hard to find it, because I believe the validation is inside de save() method... (I will try to debug using debug method (didn't know it existed)).

Comment: CakePHP does _not_ do what you're suspecting, if `Form` isn't the standard form helper though - it could still be a server side problem. You can verify that kind of thing by debugging or logging the generated view on the server (you can easily access it [in the layout](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp#L48)), or by inspecting the html using e.g. curl.

Comment: Thanks AD7Six for that push. I will have a more closer look knowing that there's no such transformations on cake by default.

Comment: It was a bootstrap issue. Nothing cakePHP related. It seems that bootstrap, under certain circumstances, doesn't reset the button, so we have to force that reset. Something like: `$('input:submit').click(function(){` ... `submitButton.button('reset');` -

Answer (score 0):

just for grin's try this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Go for it'); ?>
```

end can provide the submit button.  If this works then you probably have something overwriting the value of the submit.  I'd start looking in your $this->request->data to see what its sending over to the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Chris, actually, it was indeed something related with bootstrap, and nothing to do with cake. It was a js issue.